# Different Python logging handlers doesnt work

Tags: python, sql, logging

I have different logging handlers in Python 3.7.

First is the `SqliteHandler`, second is the `FileHandler`, third is `ConsoleHandler`.

- When I work with `SqliteHandler` alone, it works fine
- When I work with `FileHandler` and `ConsoleHandler` together, the `FileHandler` and `ConsoleHandler` both work fine

But when I try to work with `SqliteHandler` and `FileHandler` together, Python fails on `Filehandler`:

> TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

I think  the problem is with different format for `SqliteHandler` and `ConsoleHandler`. I try normalize formats, but "my normalize formats" doesn't help them. (method setHandler, formatter item is not found in config, hardcoding fix)

```
import sqlite3
import logging
import datetime
import time
import sys
import json
import os
import tempfile


initial_sql = """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %(tablename)s(
                    logcheck_loggingID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                    Created datetime,
                    Source TEXT,
                    LogLevel INT,
                    LogLevelName TEXT,
                    Message TEXT,
                    Args TEXT,
                    Module TEXT,
                    FuncName TEXT,
                    LineNo INT,
                    Exception TEXT,
                    Process INT,
                    Thread TEXT,
                    ThreadName TEXT
               )"""

insertion_sql = """INSERT INTO %(tablename)s(
                    Created,
                    Source,
                    LogLevel,
                    LogLevelName,
                    Message,
                    Args,
                    Module,
                    FuncName,
                    LineNo,
                    Exception,
                    Process,
                    Thread,
                    ThreadName
               )
               VALUES (
                    '%(created_sqlText)s',
                    '%(name)s',
                    %(levelno)d,
                    '%(levelname)s',
                    '%(msg)s',
                    '%(args)s',
                    '%(module)s',
                    '%(funcName)s',
                    %(lineno)d,
                    '%(exc_text)s',
                    %(process)d,
                    '%(thread)s',
                    '%(threadName)s'
               );
               """

def addRecordMembers(record,tablename:str):
    created_datetime = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(record.created)
    t = created_datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    created_sqlText = "%s,%03d" % (t, record.msecs)
    record.created_sqlText = created_sqlText
    record.tablename = tablename    
    #strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S,%f")

class SQLiteLoggingHandler(logging.Handler):
    """
    Thread-safe logging handler for SQLite.
    """
    configuration : dict

    def __init__(self, configuration: dict):
        super().__init__()
        setHandler(self,configuration)
        self.configuration = configuration
        conn = sqlite3.connect(self.configuration["dbFilePath"])
        sql = initial_sql % {"tablename": self.configuration["tableName"]}
        conn.execute(sql)
        conn.commit()

    def emit(self, record):
        self.format(record)
        addRecordMembers(record,self.configuration["tableName"])
         
        if record.exc_info:  # for exceptions
            record.exc_text = logging._defaultFormatter.formatException(
                record.exc_info)
        #    record.exc_text = record.exc_text.replace("'","''")         ## added for fixing quotes causing error
        else:
            record.exc_text = ""

        
        record.name = record.name.replace("'", "''")
        record.levelname = record.levelname.replace("'", "''")
        record.msg = record.msg .replace("'", "''")
        record.args = str(record.args).replace("'", "''")
        record.module = record.module.replace("'", "''")
        record.funcName = record.funcName.replace("'", "''")
        record.exc_text = record.exc_text.replace("'", "''")
        record.threadName = record.threadName.replace("'", "''")

        # Insert the log record
        sql = insertion_sql % record.__dict__
        conn = sqlite3.connect(self.configuration["dbFilePath"])
        conn.execute(sql)
        conn.commit()  # not efficient, but hopefully thread-safe
        pass


def setHandler(handler:logging.Handler, config:dict):
    logLevel = logging.getLevelName(config["loggingLevel"])
    handler.setLevel(logLevel)
    if "formatter" in config:
        formatter = MyFormatter(config["formatter"])
        handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    else:
       formatter =MyFormatter("%(asctime)s;%(levelname)s;%(name)s;%(module)s;%(funcName)s;%(lineno)d;%(message)s")
       handler.setFormatter(formatter)

        

class MyFileHandler(logging.FileHandler):
    configuration:dict

    def __init__(self, configuration: dict):
        super().__init__(configuration["logFilePath"])
        self.configuration = configuration
        setHandler(self,configuration)

    def emit(self, record):
        addRecordMembers(record,"fileHandler")
        super().emit(record)

class MyConsoleHandler(logging.StreamHandler):
    configuration:dict

    def __init__(self, configuration: dict):
        super().__init__()
        self.configuration = configuration
        setHandler(self,configuration)


    def emit(self, record):
        addRecordMembers(record,"consoleHandler")
        super().emit(record)


class MyFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    "Custom logging formatter to return usecs as part of time"
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        logging.Formatter.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
       # super().__init__( *args, **kwargs)

    def formatTime(self, record, datefmt=None)->str:
        sTxt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(record.created).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        txt = "%s,%03d" % (sTxt, record.msecs) 
        return txt

loaded = False

def load(logger: logging.Logger, config: dict) -> bool:
    global loaded
    if not loaded:
        if "SQLiteLoggingHandler" in config:
            sqlConfig = config["SQLiteLoggingHandler"]
            print(
                f'Add sqlite logging... dbFilePath: {sqlConfig["dbFilePath"]}')
            print(
                f'Add sqlite logging... tableName: {sqlConfig["tableName"]}')
            print(
                f'Add sqlite logging... loggingLevel: {sqlConfig["loggingLevel"]}')


            sqlHandler = SQLiteLoggingHandler(sqlConfig)

            logger.addHandler(sqlHandler)
            loaded = True
        if "FileHandler" in config:
            fileConfig = config["FileHandler"]
            print(
                f'Add file logging... logFilePath: {fileConfig["logFilePath"]}')
            print(
                f'Add file logging... loggingLevel: {fileConfig["loggingLevel"]}')
            print(
                f'Add file logging... formatter: {fileConfig["formatter"]}')

            fileHandler = MyFileHandler(fileConfig)
            logger.addHandler(fileHandler)
            loaded = True
        if "ConsoleHandler" in config:
            consoleConfig = config["ConsoleHandler"]
            print(
                f'Add Console logging... loggingLevel: {consoleConfig["loggingLevel"]}')
            print(
                f'Add Console logging... formatter: {consoleConfig["formatter"]}')

            consoleHandler = MyConsoleHandler(consoleConfig)
            logger.addHandler(consoleHandler)
            loaded = True
        if not loaded:
            print(
                "SQLiteLoggingHandler  or FileHandler or ConsoleHandler item not found in logging configuration.")

    return loaded


def test_main():
    dbFilePath = os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), "loggingHandlers.sqlite")
    logFilePath = os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), "loggingHandlers.log")
    if os.path.exists(dbFilePath):
        os.remove(dbFilePath)
    if os.path.exists(logFilePath):
        os.remove(logFilePath)

    config = {
         "ConsoleHandler": {
            "loggingLevel": "DEBUG",
            "formatter": "%(asctime)s;%(levelname)s;%(name)s;%(module)s;%(funcName)s;%(lineno)d;%(message)s;%(threadName)s"
              
        },
        "SQLiteLoggingHandler": {
            "dbFilePath": dbFilePath,
            "tableName": "monit_logging",
            "loggingLevel": "DEBUG"
        },
        "DISABLED_FileHandler": {
            "logFilePath": logFilePath,
            "loggingLevel": "DEBUG",
            "formatter": "%(asctime)s;%(levelname)s;%(name)s;%(module)s;%(funcName)s;%(lineno)d;%(message)s"
              
        },
       
    }

    logger = logging.getLogger()
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    load(logger, config)

    # test
    logging.info('Start')
    logging.info('End')
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_main()
```

Comment: Thank you for your formating of my text, @marc_s !

Answer (score 0):

The reason of problem is the method `SQLiteLoggingHandler.emit`. The method `SQLiteLoggingHandler.emit`  changes `record` variable ( for example property `record.args` ) and thus logging methods doesn't work.

The fixed code is:

```
  myRecord = {}
  ...
  myRecord["args"] = str(record.args).replace("'", "''")
  ...
  sql = insertion_sql % myRecord
```

instead of

```
  record.args = str(record.args).replace("'", "''")
  ...
  sql = insertion_sql % record.__dict__
```

The full code of fixed module is:

```
import sqlite3
import logging
import datetime
import time
import sys
import json
import os
import tempfile


initial_sql = """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %(tablename)s(
                    logcheck_loggingID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                    Created datetime,
                    Source TEXT,
                    LogLevel INT,
                    LogLevelName TEXT,
                    Message TEXT,
                    Args TEXT,
                    Module TEXT,
                    FuncName TEXT,
                    LineNo INT,
                    Exception TEXT,
                    Process INT,
                    Thread TEXT,
                    ThreadName TEXT
            )"""

insertion_sql = """INSERT INTO %(tablename)s(
                    Created,
                    Source,
                    LogLevel,
                    LogLevelName,
                    Message,
                    Args,
                    Module,
                    FuncName,
                    LineNo,
                    Exception,
                    Process,
                    Thread,
                    ThreadName
            )
            VALUES (
                    '%(created_sqlText)s',
                    '%(name)s',
                    %(levelno)d,
                    '%(levelname)s',
                    '%(msg)s',
                    '%(args)s',
                    '%(module)s',
                    '%(funcName)s',
                    %(lineno)d,
                    '%(exc_text)s',
                    %(process)d,
                    '%(thread)s',
                    '%(threadName)s'
            );
            """


def addRecordMembers(record, tablename: str):
    created_datetime = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(record.created)
    t = created_datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    created_sqlText = "%s,%03d" % (t, record.msecs)
    record.created_sqlText = created_sqlText
    record.tablename = tablename
    # strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S,%f")


class SQLiteLoggingHandler(logging.Handler):
    """
    Thread-safe logging handler for SQLite.
    """
    configuration: dict

    def __init__(self, configuration: dict):
        super().__init__()
        setHandler(self, configuration)
        self.configuration = configuration
        conn = sqlite3.connect(self.configuration["dbFilePath"])
        sql = initial_sql % {"tablename": self.configuration["tableName"]}
        conn.execute(sql)
        conn.commit()

    def format(self, record):
        super().format(record)

    def emit(self, record):
        self.format(record)
        addRecordMembers(record, self.configuration["tableName"])

        myRecord = {}

        if record.exc_info:  # for exceptions
            exc_text = logging._defaultFormatter.formatException(
                record.exc_info)
        else:
            exc_text = ""

        myRecord["exc_text"] = exc_text.replace("'", "''")
        myRecord["process"] = record.process
        myRecord["thread"] = record.thread
        myRecord["tablename"] = record.tablename 

        myRecord["created_sqlText"] = record.created_sqlText 
        myRecord["name"] = record.name.replace("'", "''")
        myRecord["levelno"] = record.levelno
        myRecord["lineno"] = record.lineno

        myRecord["levelname"] = record.levelname.replace("'", "''")
        myRecord["msg"] = record.msg .replace("'", "''")
        myRecord["args"] = str(record.args).replace("'", "''")
        myRecord["module"] = record.module.replace("'", "''")
        myRecord["funcName"] = record.funcName.replace("'", "''")
        myRecord["threadName"] = record.threadName.replace("'", "''")

        # Insert the log record
        sql = insertion_sql % myRecord
        conn = sqlite3.connect(self.configuration["dbFilePath"])
        conn.execute(sql)
        conn.commit()  # not efficient, but hopefully thread-safe
        pass


def setHandler(handler:logging.Handler, config:dict):
    logLevel = logging.getLevelName(config["loggingLevel"])
    handler.setLevel(logLevel)
    if "formatter" in config:
        formatter = MyFormatter(config["formatter"])
        handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    else:
    formatter =MyFormatter("%(asctime)s;%(levelname)s;%(name)s;%(module)s;%(funcName)s;%(lineno)d;%(message)s")
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)

        

class MyFileHandler(logging.FileHandler):
    configuration:dict

    def __init__(self, configuration: dict):
        super().__init__(configuration["logFilePath"])
        self.configuration = configuration
        setHandler(self,configuration)

    def format(self, record):
        return super().format(record)


    def emit(self, record):
        addRecordMembers(record,"fileHandler")
        super().emit(record)

class MyConsoleHandler(logging.StreamHandler):
    configuration:dict

    def __init__(self, configuration: dict):
        super().__init__()
        self.configuration = configuration
        setHandler(self,configuration)

    def format(self, record):
        return super().format(record)

    def emit(self, record):
        addRecordMembers(record,"consoleHandler")
        super().emit(record)


class MyFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    "Custom logging formatter to return usecs as part of time"
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        logging.Formatter.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    # super().__init__( *args, **kwargs)

    def formatTime(self, record, datefmt=None)->str:
        sTxt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(record.created).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        txt = "%s,%03d" % (sTxt, record.msecs) 
        return txt

loaded = False

def load(logger: logging.Logger, config: dict) -> bool:
    global loaded
    if not loaded:
        if "SQLiteLoggingHandler" in config:
            sqlConfig = config["SQLiteLoggingHandler"]
            print(
                f'Add sqlite logging... dbFilePath: {sqlConfig["dbFilePath"]}')
            print(
                f'Add sqlite logging... tableName: {sqlConfig["tableName"]}')
            print(
                f'Add sqlite logging... loggingLevel: {sqlConfig["loggingLevel"]}')


            sqlHandler = SQLiteLoggingHandler(sqlConfig)

            logger.addHandler(sqlHandler)
            loaded = True
        if "FileHandler" in config:
            fileConfig = config["FileHandler"]
            print(
                f'Add file logging... logFilePath: {fileConfig["logFilePath"]}')
            print(
                f'Add file logging... loggingLevel: {fileConfig["loggingLevel"]}')
            print(
                f'Add file logging... formatter: {fileConfig["formatter"]}')

            fileHandler = MyFileHandler(fileConfig)
            logger.addHandler(fileHandler)
            loaded = True
        if "ConsoleHandler" in config:
            consoleConfig = config["ConsoleHandler"]
            print(
                f'Add Console logging... loggingLevel: {consoleConfig["loggingLevel"]}')
            print(
                f'Add Console logging... formatter: {consoleConfig["formatter"]}')

            consoleHandler = MyConsoleHandler(consoleConfig)
            logger.addHandler(consoleHandler)
            loaded = True
    
        if not loaded:
            print(
                "SQLiteLoggingHandler  or FileHandler or ConsoleHandler item not found in logging configuration.")

    return loaded


def test_main():
    dbFilePath = os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), "loggingHandlers.sqlite")
    logFilePath = os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), "loggingHandlers.log")
    if os.path.exists(dbFilePath):
        os.remove(dbFilePath)
    if os.path.exists(logFilePath):
        os.remove(logFilePath)

    config = {
        "ConsoleHandler": {
            "loggingLevel": "DEBUG",
            "formatter": "%(asctime)s;%(levelname)s;%(name)s;%(module)s;%(funcName)s;%(lineno)d;%(message)s;%(threadName)s"
            
        },
        "SQLiteLoggingHandler": {
            "dbFilePath": dbFilePath,
            "tableName": "monit_logging",
            "loggingLevel": "DEBUG"
        },
        "FileHandler": {
            "logFilePath": logFilePath,
            "loggingLevel": "DEBUG",
            "formatter": "%(asctime)s;%(levelname)s;%(name)s;%(module)s;%(funcName)s;%(lineno)d;%(message)s"
            
        },
    
    }
    
    print (dbFilePath)
    print (logFilePath)
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    load(logger, config)

    # test
    logging.info('Start')
    logging.info('End')
    return     
    conn = sqlite3.connect(dbFilePath)
    cursor = conn.execute("SELECT * FROM monit_logging")
    columnnames = [description[0] for description in cursor.description]
    print(columnnames)
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    prints = []
    for r in rows:
        print(f"{columnnames[0]}: {r[0]}, {r[columnnames.index('Message')]}")
        prints.append(
            f"{columnnames[0]}: {r[0]}, {r[columnnames.index('Message')]}")
    expected = """logcheck_loggingID: 1, Start
logcheck_loggingID: 2, End"""
    print ("\n".join(prints))
    # return assert expected == "\n".join(prints)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_main()
```